More granular watch information
I have a situation where the application that I'm working on involves a few lengthy lists which undergird watches. When I say lengthy, the lists can be anything from a thousand, up to ten thousand items long. The watches are deep and update other lists which in-turn have watches.
We're running into performance problems due to the aggregate effect of having to update the lists, mostly as a result of Vue's need to reattach callbacks on the watched items.
It occurs to me that it could be quite useful to have a model where the callback function could not only receive the updated object or list that's being watched, but also information about what specifically has changed. This would provide a means to build performant applications, when, for example a typical modification to a list or object is minor (addition/removal or update of a single item).
I am aware of the fact that deep watches should be avoided; unfortunately, this is a legacy situation which has been inherited.
Is there any means of getting more granular information around reactive effects in Vue?

There's no such public api. The way this needs to be solved depends on your case. This is primarily design problem. You have  this information at the time you modify the state, so it needs to not be lost. You need granular state in order to set many granular watchers, or emit custom events. This is also why the use of global store for local state can be justified, granular changes can be tracked to specific actions or mutations and be subscribed to, e.g. Pinia. It also allows to subscribe to state changes with more precision than a watcher but it likely doesn't have granularity you need

the problem is solvable but needs elaboration, in short use shallowReactive for lists, and reactive Vue ES classes for list items
